# Smooth div scrolling issue on Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, html, scroll

I have a problem with smooth div scrolling. I using jquery.scrollTo-1.4.3.1 library to "move" a div on my website. It works great, but not on Google Chrome, where it looks like having low FPS. I noticed (but I'm not sure), that problem occurs only sometimes and disappears on cache clean.
How can I check what's wrong or try to clean cache in javascript?
Thanks for help.

PS: I test website on 4 computers and everybody have this problem...

EDIT:

Website is available under: http://imap.stackoverflow.octibse.com/

Comment: fiddle, code or link ?

Comment: P.S - Make the website public

Comment: Can you provide any more information?